# Text button text all caps for older api 8

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I am using android studio 2.1.2 and I need to design a app for api level 8 (android froyo). But I come up with 2 problem one is if I choose blank activity then is shows the rendering issue and second one is all the button text is appearing on capital letter. After some time on google I found that android:textAllCaps="false" but the issue is the property is not supported by the Api level 8 it requires minimum level 14. It will be very helpful if some one can able to solve this. I suppose that is is a matter of theme but most of the theme is not supported by lower api, I use different theme also but the problem remains, if any one knows a specific theme which don't force to make all the text to be caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your Activity

mButton.setTransformationMethod(null);

Comment: thank you, it works. Can you tell me about blank activity rendering issue it is also one which bothers me.

Comment: can you post a picture of it ? normally you can close it and work cant explain without checking exactly